# Singularity and charts-problems met in Dirac quantization condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, condensed-matter, differential-geometry, topological-field-theory

Context:

45'23'' in a lecture given by Professor Wu, https://www.koushare.com/video/videodetail/4619.

Consider a vector field $\vec{A}(\vec{x})$, with $\nabla\times\vec{A}(\vec{x})=\vec{B}(\vec{x})=g\frac{\vec{x}}{x^{3}}$, it's followed that $\vec{A}(\vec{x})$ has at least one singularity on any spehre surrounding the origin (0,0,0).

Then the lecture says due to singularity (singularies) on the sphere, we can use two charts, whose overlop contain the equator of the sphere. Then we can define two new vector field $\vec{A1}(\vec{x})$ and $\vec{A2}(\vec{x})$, each of which is regular on corresponding charts. $\vec{A1}(\vec{x})$ and $\vec{A2}(\vec{x})$ differ by a gauge transformation in the overlap.

My question is:

1. How to understand that using different charts can lift singularity.
2. Why not more charts， or why not charts of other shape? Are there any requirements in the choice of charts?

Answer (score 1):

This question is really just one about coordinate systems on a sphere.  You cannot put a single map on the surface of a sphere without having at least 2 coordinate singularities.  Think of the poles on Earth, which are both degenerate.  If you put separate coordinate systems, for example but not necessarily, for the Northern and the Southern Hemispheres, neither has to have a singularity. You want them at least to touch so that everything is covered by at least one of the maps. Having them overlap a bit is better for technical reasons of how you switch over from one map to the other if needed. On the sphere, each of the two charts can be Cartesian. You *could* do more, but you only need two in this case.

Comment: A very simple yet straightforward picture for understanding, Thank you. Yet two more questions: 1. If n poles, then we'll have n charts? 2. As we know, sometimes, a singularity of a function f may have order m, i.e. f\propto (1/r)^{m}, will the order m influence?

Comment: More information here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology).  The minimal number of charts in an atlas depends on the manifold structure. The answer I gave was good for the sphere and I think *maybe* for any orientable manifold of dimension 2. For more general manifolds there are theorems, but they are hard theorems beyond me. I think related is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusternik%E2%80%93Schnirelmann_category